# Case insensitive GREP in Perl

Tags: linux, perl, grep

I have a Perl script which is using strict

```
use strict
```

I want to grep an element from array by using case in-sensitive comparison with a var that i have

```
my ($sPermIdIndex) = grep $aHeaderLine[$_] eq $sPermIdField/i, 0 .. $#aHeaderLine;
```

This line give me error

```
Bareword "i" not allowed while "strict subs" in use
```

How to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: The Perl fragment `/i` can be part of a `s///` substitution and written as `s/something/replacement/i` to indicate a case insensitive search. When used as in the code above, the `/` in the `/i` is likely to be interpreted as the divide operator, hence divide by `i`. But in that interpretation the `i` is a bareword and hence the error is generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can foldcase both strings using [`fc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fc.html) and compare them

```
my ($sPermIdIndex) = grep { 
  # use v5.16; or prefix with CORE::
  CORE::fc($aHeaderLine[$_]) eq CORE::fc($sPermIdField) 
}
0 .. $#aHeaderLine;
```

It works the same as using regex `$aHeaderLine[$_] =~ /^\Q$sPermIdField\E\z/i`.

Comment: yes. I will. It isnt allowing me for now. As it say I cannot accept answer within 7 mins.. lol..

Answer (score 5):

You can compare two things case insensitively if you [foldcase](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fc.html) them before comparison:

```
fc("Foo") eq fc("fOO")
```